# exists() condition performance issue

Tags: sql-server-2012, exists, query-performance

I have a simple SQL query (see below) that runs indefinitely long (I wasn't able to wait for its completion)

```
if exists(
    select 1 
    from [files].[Contacts_Migration_Template] c 
    where not exists(select 1 
                     from [files].[Additional_Contact_Migration_Template] 
                     where contact = c.[migration id])
) print 'warning message'
```

but subquery  *(if exists(**subquery**) print 'warning message')*  itself is executed immediately (see screenshots below)

**"full" query**
[image]

**subquery**
[image]

Generated estimated execution plan (see below) for both queries shows that subquery must have higher query cost than "full" query... wherein, as I say above, the first (subquery) running immediately, and the second ("full") running infinitely long ...

[image]

what's going on?

---

**ORIGINAL QUERY**

[image]

Comment: The fast one uses a hash join and only scans `Additional_Contact_Migration_Template` once. The slow one scans it (or at least a spooled copy) multiple times. Are statistics up to date?

Comment: but why relative query cost for first is 83% (against 17%) if it is faster?

Comment: It is based on estimates which are wrong. It probably assumes the number of executions of the inner side of the nested loops will be much smaller than actually happens in reality. Might be a case of [row goals gone rogue](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18637/unexpected-scans-during-delete-operation-using-where-in/18746#18746) actually.

Comment: it is still too simple query to go so long :) furthermode subquery works fast and outside exists() only need to make a print/throw

Comment: If you add the missing index then it should solve the problem. Or you can use query hints to force a hash join instead of nested loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used temp table to break execution sequence. It helped.

```
select 1 [x] into #tmp_87624435
from [files].[Contacts_Migration_Template] c
where not exists( select 1
    from [files].[Additional_Contact_Migration_Template]
    where contact = c.[migration id]);
if exists(select 1 from #tmp_87624435) throw 51000, 'warning', 1;
```

but I still think that even this is overkill for such a simple problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if exists(

    select 1 from [files].[Contacts_Migration_Template] c left join 
    [files].[Additional_Contact_Migration_Template] a
    on c.[migration id]=a.contact 
    where a.contact is null
       )

print 'warning message'
```

Comment: see my corrections in the post (I added original query) - originally I had joins but they, too, have worked long

Comment: i cant see your images due to some checkpoints in my office. So did you use left join in your query?

Comment: yes it is. Initially, I used exactly the same query, as you wrote :)

Comment: do you have proper indexes in matching columns(c.[migration id]=a.contact) on the tables?

Comment: no I haven't, but I don't want to have them for only this problem solution :) all my [files].TableName tables are generated on the fly and I do not want do add indexes for this intermediate tables - it is overkill